# Remove old synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As part of our recent tag cleanup, we've finally got around to actioning the change to the [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) tag, and this has now been renamed to [mass-effect-3-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-multiplayer). However, because it was renamed, it still has the old [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) synonyms.

Can the synonyms [online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) and [matchmaking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matchmaking) be removed from the [mass-effect-3-multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect-3-multiplayer) tag please?

[Link to mass-effect-3-multiplayer synonyms page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/mass-effect-3-multiplayer/synonyms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.